# Trying to learn how to use the "for" loop

Tags: r, if-statement, for-loop, subset

So I have this subset:

```
Sbset<-cbind(v1,v2,v3,v4,...vn)
```

and I want to do :

```
ifelse(vi==9,NA,vi) for every vi, i=1,...,n
```

and I want to learn to use the for loop to do it (I know I can do it other ways).

So I tried :

```
V<-colnames(Sbset)

for(i in seq_along(V)){
ifelse(Sbset[, Sbset[i]]==9,NA,Sbset[i])
}
```

However, it does nothing. 
So I know that I am not understanding how to use the for logic. 
Could you please help me ?
Thank you :)

Comment: `Sbset[, Sbset[i]]` is not the column since `Sbset[i]` is not the name of the column. You need `names(Sbset)[i]` instead. Similar change later on.

Comment: Once you know how to use the `for` loop approach, you can look at simpler ways that R provides, for example in this case you could just do `is.na(Sbset) <- Sbset == 9`

Comment: This is not an R-specific problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a dataset

```
v1 <- sample(10,5)
v2 <- sample(10,5)
v3 <- sample(10,5)
v4 <- sample(10,5)
Sbset <-cbind(v1,v2,v3,v4)
Sbset
#     v1 v2 v3 v4
#[1,]  8  1  6  4
#[2,]  7  7  4  1
#[3,]  3  6  5  2
#[4,]  5  5  3  5
#[5,] 10  9  9  7
```

Use the loop

```
for (i in 1:ncol(Sbset)){
    Sbset[,i] <- ifelse(Sbset[,i]==9,NA,Sbset[,i])
}
Sbset
#      v1 v2 v3 v4
# [1,]  8  1  6  4
# [2,]  7  7  4  1
# [3,]  3  6  5  2
# [4,]  5  5  3  5
# [5,] 10 NA NA  7
```

But it's preferable not to use a loop

```
Sbsetpaul <-cbind(v1,v2,v3,v4) # Recreate the dataset
Sbsetpaul[Sbsetpaul == 9] <- NA
```

or even as suggested by @Frank

```
Sbsetfrank <-cbind(v1,v2,v3,v4) # Recreate the dataset
is.na(Sbsetfrank) <- Sbsetfrank == 9
```

Comment: Very nice answer. How can I make it so the variables themselves are modified ? So that when I look at them in summary(vi), I see no 9, only NAs at their place ?

Comment: `Sbset` is a matrix. You can reassign the first column of the matrix to the vector v1 with `v1 <- Sbset[,1]`, then you will see NAs in `summary(v1)`. But usually many vectors are kept in a data frame: `Sbsetnicolas <- data.frame(Sbset)`. Then columns are accessed with `$`. `summary(Sbsetnicolas$v1)`.